# Make a class to call its notify() from another Class in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

Is there *anyway* to make class A call notify() inside of it, to awake threads on wait() for that object's lock, **from a thread running in background**?

thanks.

**EDIT:**

Please ignore unnecessary code. I wanted to show you how I have really implemented it.

Messenger is a serialized object.

A thread "ServerHandler" will call 
`bufferImpObject.put(<Messenger Obj>, <ServerHandler instance>, <socket instance>)`

```
public class BufferImp {
    private Messenger[] requests;
    public  static int req_size;
    public static int req_count;


     Socket s;
     Messenger msg;
     InputStream is;
     ObjectInputStream ois;
     OutputStream os;
     ObjectOutputStream oos;



    public BufferImp(int size) {
        this.req_size = size;
        this.req_count = 0;
        requests = new Messenger[size];

    }



     class CheckWaitThread extends Thread{
        Thread t;
        String s;
        Socket incoming_socket;



        CheckWaitThread(String s, Thread t, Socket incoming_socket){
            this.t = t;
            this.s = s;
            this.incoming_socket = incoming_socket;


        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
               // I want to keep on checking till slots are FREE
               // IF FREE, call notify() of BufferImp to get back WAITING (inactive) ServerHandler thread
               if(t.getState().equals(State.WAITING)){ 
                              os = incoming_socket.getOutputStream();
                              AppendableObjectOutputStream oosa = new AppendableObjectOutputStream(os);
                              oosa.writeObject(new Messenger("bufferFull", null, "true"));


                }
                t.join();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BufferImp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BufferImp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    // insert incoming Message objects into "requests" queue 
    public synchronized boolean put(Messenger o, Thread t, Socket s) throws InterruptedException {


        while(req_size == req_count) {
            CheckWaitThread cw = new CheckWaitThread("<----------CheckWaitThread----------->", t, s);
            cw.start();
            wait(); 


        }

        // these parts need to be executed when notify() is called.
        requests[cur_req_in] = o;
        cur_req_in = (cur_req_in + 1) % req_size;
        req_count++;
        notifyAll();
        Messenger msg = (Messenger) o;


        return true;
    }




}
```

Comment: please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, with some sample snippets.

Comment: please help us understanding the problem by providing more details , thanks

Comment: That is too much code :) You must shorten it to the smallest possible sample that you can -- it makes it easier for others to review it but often helps you identify the core issue/concept as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer to your question is No.

Your question is very unclear, but I think this is what you are asking:

- Class A extends `Thread` and `Runnable` and a thread is running with some `A`object as target. Call it AThread.
- That thread is owning a lock on the A Object and other threads (OThread) are waiting on that.
- You want some other thread (BgThread) to be able wake up the waiting threads.

The important point is that notify can be only be called from a **thread** that **own the lock**. So if the background thread does not own the lock then it cannot call notify on it.

EDIT:

Looking at the code you added, it seems you are trying to build a wait mechanism in `BufferImp`: if the `requests` is filled to capacity, then `CheckWaitThread` will write a bufferFull message to the incoming socket, so that presumably the clients will stop sending more requests. And the somehow (because of other threads popping and processing requests) at some future time the machine will start spinning again.

**There is no need to work so hard**

- Why do you need to send the response and wait for the `requests` collection to free up in a separate thread? Why can't you send it from this thread itself?
- Instead of managing `requests array` yourself, look at [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) which created exactly this purpose.

Comment: +1 Appreciate your support. It's a must to use **wait(), notify() or notifyAll()** since this is for an academic project.

Comment: The reason for using that seperate thread to wait for requests is, without that the entire GUI got frozen, I'm not calling wait() on EDT. I confirmed it by calling Thread.currentThread.getName() just before wait(). any clue?

Comment: Not blocking GUI is good but in this case `put` is essentially blocking while `requests` array is full. But now I am confused. Does this mean your GUI thread is reading requests from socket? That does not seem right.

Answer (score 0):

All code is run in a thread and the difference between background and foreground is notional.

To call notify() you only have to lock the object notified.